# How to change to handlebars while displaying data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

> I am using Handlebars to display my content, How will this following
>   code in ejs be displayed in handlebars to display data. I currently
>   new to Nodejs , can someone suggest possible solution
>
> **And which is better to use ,ejs or handlebars**

```
 <% if(files){ %>
              <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                  <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                    <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                    <% } else { %>
                      <%= file.filename %>
                        <% } %>
                          <form method="POST" action="/files/<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                          </form>
                </div>
                <% }) %>
                  <% } else { %>
                    <p>No files to show</p>
                    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          {{#each files}}
            <div class="card card-body mb-3">
              {{#if this.isImage}}
                <img src="image/{{this.filename}}" alt="">
              {{else}}
                {{this.filename}}
              {{/if}}
                      <form method="POST" action="/files/{{this._id}}?_method=DELETE">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                      </form>
            </div>
           {{else}}
                <p>No files to show</p>
           {{/each}}
```

[here](https://developer.ibm.com/node/2014/11/11/compare-javascript-templates-jade-mustache-dust/) you can find the comparaison between different javascript templating engines.